# Why the user is redirected to the login page instead of homepage when he clicks in the logo link?

Tags: php, laravel

When the user click in the link "Login" the user goes to the page "http://project.test/login". In this page if I click in the logo that is this link:

```
<a href="{{route('home')}}">LOGO</a>
```

The user should go to the home page "http://project.test/", but the user remains in the page "http://project.test/login".

Do you know why?

LoginController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class LoginController extends Controller
{

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
        return redirect()->intended($this->redirectTo);
    }
}
```

Routes:

```
Auth::routes();


Route::get('auth/{provider}', [
    'uses' => 'OauthController@redirectToProvider',
    'as' => 'social.auth'
]);

Route::get('auth/{provider}/callback', [
    'uses' => 'OauthController@handleProviderCallback',
]);


Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::get('/', [
    'uses' => 'FrontController@index',
    'as'   =>'index'
]);
```

Comment: What is the definition of your home route?

Comment: Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Comment: The default laravel home route if you haven't changed it requires login because it's meant to be the user's home. Perhaps you should do `<a href="{{route('/')}}">LOGO</a>` instead

Comment: Can you show us your routes, please?

Comment: I updated the question with routes.

Comment: Ok, so you have a home for guests and a home for authenticated users? Guest can access / but they can't access /home. In this way if you are not logged in and you try to reach /home the systems redirects to the login page.. cause /home is only accessible for logged users. Am i right?

Comment: Thanks, so do you know how to properly fix the issue?

Comment: @apokryfos comment is the correct answer if you want to keep the current route names, but in this way you re not going to use a named route for logo. If you want to use named routes you have to fix your route names. What's the difference in homepage between logged and  unlogged? users will have a dashboard or?

Comment: The login users can create posts edit user account, etc. The unlogged user can just access, search for posts.

Comment: With "<a href="{{route('/')}}">LOGO</a>" it appears "Route [/] not defined", but it is "Route::get('/', [
    'uses' => 'FrontController@index',
    'as'   =>'index'
]);" in the web.php file.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry use route('index'). 

However, the `FrontController@index` and `HomeController@index` will show the same view?

Comment: Yes, or its not correct having two routes for the same page? Even if one is for authenticated and other for no authenticated users?

Comment: You can do whatever you want actually, but it makes more sense to have different routes for different pages. With controller and view you can handle if the user is logged or not and change the page content. Is up to you... however, if my last comment works i'll add an answer so you can choose it. If you want to "fix" views, routes and so on to make them more "correct" that's another thing and should not affect this question. We might go offtopic

Comment: Its ok, maybe I ask other question because Im not understanding the process to have only one route for both authenticated and unauthenticated. But so you can answer so is possible to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments at the end of the discussion, replace

```
<a href="{{route('home')}}">LOGO</a>
```

with

```
<a href="{{route('index')}}">LOGO</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your link of the logo from `<a href="{{route('home')}}">LOGO</a>` to `<a href="{{ url('/home') }}">LOGO</a>`. Don't change anything else just keep as it is.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set your route to

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

Comment: Thanks, like this it appears Route [home] not defined.

Comment: Change protected $redirectTo = '/home'; to protected $redirectTo = '/';

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to add or change routes like

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

So simple like that in your view

```
<a href="{{route('home')}}">LOGO</a>
```

And if your user is log don't forget to use a return on your Routes and define it in middleware if you are using the Laravel 5.X

Try this

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
if ( $user->isAdmin() ) {// do your margic here
    return redirect()->route('dashboard');
}

 return redirect('/home');
}
```